# (Blazor) Why child razor component not working?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, parent-child, blazor, code-behind

I'm trying to include child component to parent component

But child component is not working

Below is the code

```
==================== parent component razor ====================
<InfoDialog @ref="infoDialog"></InfoDialog>
```

```
==================== parent component code behind ====================
public InfoDialog infoDialog { get; set; }

public async Task AddToDB()
{
    infoDialog.Show("success", "request complete!");
}
```

```
==================== child component razor ====================
<MatDialog @bind-IsOpen="@IsShow">
    <MatDialogTitle>@Title</MatDialogTitle>
    <MatDialogContent>
        <p>@Description</p>
    </MatDialogContent>
    <MatDialogActions>
        <MatButton OnClick="@Close">OK</MatButton>
    </MatDialogActions>
</MatDialog>
```

```
==================== child component code behind ====================
public partial class InfoDialog
{
    public bool IsShow { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public void Show(string _title, string _Description)
    {
        IsShow = true;
        Title = _title;
        Description = _Description;
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        IsShow = false;
    }
}
```

When I called the 'AddToDB' function, I call the show function of the child component, but the child component is not rendered. Would any one please help me?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: I added this.StateHasChanged(); under infoDialog.Show(). But now woking as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `StateHasChanged()` in your child component methods.

```
public void Show(string _title, string _Description)
{
    IsShow = true;
    Title = _title;
    Description = _Description;
    StateHasChanged();
}

public void Close()
{
    IsShow = false;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```